# Get attachments from a post

Tags: plugin-development, comments, query-posts, attachments, images

I created a snippet to get all attachment from a post, included attachments from comments.

```
<?php 

$post_attachments = get_posts( array (
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_parent' => $post->ID

));

?>
<ul class="attach-list-post">
<?php 
foreach ( $post_attachments as $post_attachment ) {
    $name = $post_attachment->post_title;
    $date = $post_attachment->post_date;
    echo '<li>' . wp_get_attachment_link( $post_attachment->ID, '', false, false ) . $name . $date . '</li>';
} 
?>
</ul>
```

It returns also the date of the attachment. 
Now, I need to return also the username of the user who attached the file, that can be the user who commented the post.
I've tried using:

```
$author = $post_attachment->post_author;
```

but it doesn't return any kind of value.

Any suggestion on this?

Answer (score 0):

$post_attachment->post_author will return user ID. You need to fetch user details from user ID.

get_userdata( $userid );